# br tag doesn't work when getting data from controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have controller with this code.

```
ViewData["Content"] = "Hello. <br /> This is testing text."
```

This is my view

```
<h3>Testing code in view. <br /> 12345</h3>
<h3>@ViewData["Content"]</h3>
```

The br tag in the first h3 works perfectly. But in the second h3, it doesn't work. The browser show the original text with br tag inside. And I want to break after "Hello". I don't know why and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `@Html.Encode`

Comment: Try this : 'ViewData["Content"] = MvcHtmlString.Create( "Hello" + "<br />" + "This is testing text" );'

Comment: ViewData["Content"] = MvcHtmlString.Create( "Hello" + "<br />" + "This is testing text" ); It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <h3>@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.Encode(ViewData["Content"])))</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to convert it somehow with htmlentities() function?
Check this [manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Also, give some additional info about system you use.